# How to use proxy properties with ObservableCollections

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

According to the MVVM design pattern I would like to use proxy properties to change Model properties in the ViewModel, e.g.

```
public string Description 
{
  get {return this.UnderlyingModelInstance.Description; }
  set 
  {
    this.UnderlyingModelInstance.Description = value;
    this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Description");
  }
}
```

**Question**: How would I write such proxy properties if the Model I am accessing is inside an ObservableCollection?

Model I am trying to access:

```
public class MeasurementItem
    {
        public double Position { get; set; }

        public double Result { get; set; }

        public MeasurementType Type { get; set; }

        public MeasurementDirection Direction { get; set; }
    }
```

Model of OC:

```
public class MeasurementCollector
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MeasurementItem> Measurements = new ObservableCollection<MeasurementItem>();
    }
```

Simplified ViewModel:

```
public class ProgramEditorViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private MeasurementCollector _measurementCollector = new MeasurementCollector();


        public ObservableCollection<MeasurementItem> MeasurementViewList
        {
            get { return _measurementCollector.Measurements; }
        }


        public double Position
        {
            get ??
            set ??
        }
 
        etc..
```

View:

```
<!-- Diameter input -->
        <Label Content="Diameter: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Position}" Width="80" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <!-- Result output -->
        <Label Content="Result: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Result}" Width="80" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <Label Content="Direction: " Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Direction}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0 5 0 5" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: Can you show how is set data context in view?

Comment: Presumably your proxy class holds an instance variable of the underlying `MeasurementItem`?  Then it's simply `ObservableCollection<ProxyClass>`.

Comment: Otherwise, what I really think you need is to simply implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `MeasurementItem` class.

Comment: @Vernou in de code-behind of the view I put the following assignment in the constructor: DataContext = new ProgramEditorViewModel();

Comment: @RobertHarvey My problem is not necessarily invoking an update, but rather how to access a Model Item via the OC.

Comment: You ViewModel have a collection, but Label, TextBox or ComboBox can display only **one** item. What collection's item you wand display? The first, the last, the selected?